# Firefox is updated again from FF14 to FF19 even if checked never check for update

Tags: firefox

Firefox is updated again from FF14 to FF19 even if checked never check for update

how to disable auto update for firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't recommend disabling updates completely as once you select "Never check for updates" only critical updates get auto installed. However, the following should work:

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Set `app.update.url` to an empty string.